# Possible data Ingest count issue in FeatureStore

Tags: python, feature-store, mlrun

I see mistake, that count of values in FeatureStore Statistic do not fit with amount of ingested values, see sample

```
...
project_name = 'test-load'
project = mlrun.get_or_create_project(project_name, context='./', user_project=True)
..
fset = fstore.FeatureSet("test01", entities=['id'])
# ingest 3 values
fstore.ingest(fset, CSVSource("mycsv", path="a1.csv"), overwrite=False)
# ingest 3 values
fstore.ingest(fset, CSVSource("mycsv", path="a2.csv"), overwrite=False)
```

and I saw only 3 values in statistic see print screen:

[image: FeatureStore statistics]

Do you see any issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is that **statistics reflect the data for the last ingestion ONLY**. It means, that number of values based on ingestions is without mistakes, you can check total of values based on e.g. FeatureVector, see sample code

```
...
features = ["test01.F_2"]

vector = fstore.FeatureVector("test_vector",features=features,with_indexes=True)
resp = fstore.get_offline_features(vector)

# Return values based on vector definition
resp.to_dataframe()
```